# Pointer Reference Pattern - Common use?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, containers

In a system where current object is operated by other contained objects, when reference to current object is passed, it appears that the link goes on and on....without any end ( For the code below, `Car->myCurrentComponent->myCar_Brake->myCurrentComponent->myCar_Brake->myCurrentComponent` ....).

I`Car` and `Car->myCurrentComponent->myCar_Brake` refer to same address, point to same objects. It's like Car contains Brake which refers to Car.

In fact, Car is the only object, myCar_Brake and myCar_Speed just refer(point) to it.Is this kind of use of reference and pointer normal? Are there any potential problem with this approach?

> Sample Code

```
class Brake
class C

class   Car
{

public:

Car();
// Objects of type B and C.
Brake*  myBrake;
Speed*  mySpeed;

// Current component under action.

Component*  myCurrentComponent;

}
/******************************/
// Constructor

Car::Car()
{
myBrake = new Brake(*this);
mySpeed = new Speed(*this);

myCurrentComponent = myBrake;
}

/******************************/
class   Brake: public   Component
{

public:

Brake(Car&);
// Needs to operate on A.
Car*    myCar_Brake;

}

// Constructor
Brake::Brake(Car&)
{
myCar_Brake = Car;
}

/******************************/
class Speed
{

public:

Speed(Car&);

// Needs to operate on A.
Car*    myCar_Speed;

}

// Constructor
Speed::Speed(Car&)
{
myCar_Speed = Car;
}

/****************************/
```

Comment: Unless Brake and speed are polymorphic then there is no need for pointers. Use objects instead.

Comment: Sorry.....Not shown, But as you pointed out, They are polymorphic.

Answer (score 5):

There's no fundamental problem with having circular references in your object graph, so long as you understand that and don't try to traverse your object graph without keeping track of which objects you've encountered.  To specifically answer your question, having circular references between objects is relatively common; it's the way a doubly-linked list works, for example.

Comment: True, but it should be noted that a doubly linked list (or a single one for that matter) is a very unusual structure when modeling real life object per the example from OP.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: it's all dependent upon the modeling.  A common real-world example: a Person has Relatives; among those Relatives are their Parents and their Children.

Comment: That would be the canonical counterexample. Still I would argue that it is uncommon for that design to be necessary.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: How can brake and speed operate on instance of Car if not done this way? What is your way of achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: @First The Brake brakes the Car and as a consequence impacts the speed (via the cars response. Maybe the brakes activates an air-brake triggered by lots of parameters. Bugatti Veyron? :-) ). So I would probably go with some event model or similar  message passing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Although, as Paul mentions, there is no problem with having circular references, the above code example is totally missing encapsulation and is not memory leak safe.

Does it make sense to allow something like this?

```
Speed::Speed(Car& value)
{
  myCar_Speed = value;
  // WTF code below
  value->myCurrentComponent->myCar_Brake = NULL;
}
```

Also,

```
Car::Car()
{
  myBrake = new Brake(*this);
  mySpeed = new Speed(*this);
  //if Speed::Speed(Car&) throws an exception, memory allocated for myBrake will leak
  myCurrentComponent = myBrake;
}
```

Never use raw pointers without some kind of a resource manager.

Answer (score 0):

Without debating the validity of the actual object structure of the relation of `Car`, `Break` and `Speed`, this approach has one minor problem: it can be in invalid states.

If - something - goes wrong, it is possible in this setup, that a `Car` instance#1 has a `Break` instance#2 that belongs to a `Car` instance#3. A general problem with doubly-linked lists too - the architecture itself enables invalid states. Of course careful visibility modifier choosing and good implementation of functions can guarantee it will not happen. And when its done and safe, you stop modifying it, take it as a 'black box', and just use it, thus eliminating the probability of screwing it up.

But, I'd personally recommend to avoid architectures that allow invalid states for high level, constantly maintained code. A doubly-linked list is a low level balck box code that will most likely not need any code changes, like ever. Can you say that about your `Car`, `Break` and `Speed`?

If a `Car` had a `Break` and `Speed`, and `Break` and `Speed` would not know of their "owning `Car`", it would be impossible to make and invalid state. Of course, it might not suit the concrete situation.

Comment: Also, in this particular setup I'd remove the backwards link from Break and Speed. Speed does not need to know about the Car which has it. Break can have a doBreaking(const Car onThisCar, Speed& currentSpeed) function to have everything it needs to operate. After all the Brake "manipulates the Speed of a specific Car" not "Has a Car and able to manipulate its Speed"